# Pentaho-server (PDI) : Home directories are not created automatically

Tags: pentaho, pdi

---

Hello,

I'm using pentaho-server 9.2.0.0.290, installed on a RHEL 8.8 server and I have a problem when a user logs in for the first time: the homedirectory is not created directly and I get the following error in the logs (example with the user toto):

```
> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: Path not found; nested exception is javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: /pentaho/tenant0/home/toto
> Caused by: javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: /pentaho/tenant0/home/toto
```

This behavior is annoying because you have to create the homeDir manually with an admin account.

For information :

- the "/pentaho/tenant0/home/" folder does not physically exist on the server, as the repo is based on a mysql backend.
- users are linked to LDAP, there is no "manual" creation of users
- the kettleproperties file is empty (default values)

I'd like to know if there's a way, through pentaho, for the homeDir to be created automatically when the user logs in for the first time, so that it doesn't have to be done manually?

To complete the information given above:

We have other machines with pentaho-server 9.0 on which homedirectories are created automatically by pentaho on first connection.

The problem arises on our new infrastructure with pentaho-server 9.2.

Could this be linked to pentaho-server version 9.2?

Best regards